# How to use parallel processing in my function to speed up processing time

Tags: python, arrays, parallel-processing, pseudocode

So lets say I have this function (bear with me I'm using pseudocode)

```
def changeText(textfile_url, ConstantParameter, googledrive_url):
 textfile = textfile_url + ConstantParameter
 send textfile to googledrive_url
```

And the textfile, and googledrive_url is stored in the array test_array.

If I would like to iterate through this array and call the function for the entirety of the array like so:

```
for x in test_array:
 changeText(x.textfile_url, ConstantParameter, x.googledrive_url)
```

How can I integrate parallel processing? As of right now it takes about a second to iterate through the loop one time.

Comment: later python versions have support for async operations https://realpython.com/async-io-python/

Comment: [`multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool) as a map function you could use.

Comment: Read up on the documentation and study the examples - there is likely an example you an adapt to your purpose. [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) is another *built-in* module you might want to try.

Comment: Note that you are talking about parallelism but what you need is *concurrency* and not parallelism. Asynchronicity help to achieve that as pointed out by some previous comments.